# how to efficiently truncate padding zeros in a string

Tags: string, language-agnostic

for example, I have a input string "1.2.3.4.0.0", output "1.2.3.4", or another input "1.2.0.3.4.0", output "1.2.0.3.4"

...
what is the most efficient and elegant way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: In what programming language ?

Comment: What do you want the following to be truncated to: a) "0" b) "0.0" c) ".0" d) "..." e) "1...000.000."?

Answer (score 1):

In any language having regular expression search & replace, replace this regexp:

```
(\.0)+$
```

with nothing.

Comment: That's a lot more useful that what I responded with.  Deleting mine and voting for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this algorithm:

```
while last character is "0" do
    remove last character
    if last character is "." then
        remove last character
    endif
endwhile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while string endswith ".0"
    string efficientlyRemoveLastTwoCharacters
```

This is very efficient (I hope everybody gets the joke).

A more efficient implementation cannot be language agnostic.